# Proving non-singularity of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm finding it difficult to prove that the following matrix is singular.

A is a square matrix with the following property,  *A^2 + 5A = I*   , where *I* is the identity matrix. Prove that A is non-singular.

I have tried using contradiction and assuming that det(A)=0, however, this leads me to a point where I am left with det(A^2 +5A)=1. I know that individually det(A*A) = det(5A) = 0, but I cannot say that det(A^2 +5A)=0 in general.

Please help!

Comment: A determinant argument will work, $\text{det}(A^2+5A)=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(A+5I)=1$, so $\text{det}(A)\ne 0$.  But I think Catalin Zara's approach is better.

Comment: @AndreNicolas Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does $A(A+5I)= I$ tell you about $A$?

Comment: Ahh I see it now, thank you!